# Redis Desktop Manager on Ubuntu 18.04: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1

Tags: redis, desktop, zlib

I had redis-desktop-manager.rdm installed via snap on Ubuntu 18.04 and it was working for a day and then after a minor auto system update, it broke with

```
/snap/redis-desktop-manager/150/opt/redis-desktop-manager/rdm: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

zlib1g is already the newest version and zlib1g:i386 didn't solve the problem.

I don't see anything relevant on /var/log/apt/history.log to see what broke it so how do I restore the *suddenly* missing libz.so.1?

Comment: Same story here on Ubuntu 16.